# How to set street obstructed in planet_osm_line/pg_route

Tags: openstreetmap, postgis, pgrouting

I am working on a project where we are going to be looking at finding the shortest/fastest route from point A to point B.  I've been looking at the tables generated by the osm2pgsql.  And I'm wondering how would I represent a road obstructed after the osm has been loaded into our database.  Our project will rely on osm to map out all of the roads we will also have an operator looking at live video footage of roads.  At which point if the operator see's a road is obstructed we want to update the database to reflect this road obstructed say by a downed tree.

I've been looking at all of the columns and the only one that stands out in my head is barrier.  I have been unable to find any documentation on what each column represents and how pg_route takes each into consideration when creating a route.  What I'm looking for is a column that when pg_route looks in the database and sees a road it says oh that roads blocked skip it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is good question for gis.se...

First thing is pg_routing can't route via data generated by osm2pgsql - this data is not a network. You need data generated by osm2po or osm2pgrouting and this data is quite different.

Second thing is - there is no such column. In every pg_routing function you're passing sql which will select data for route search so you're deciding which edge will be in this dataset and which not - it's not a problem to add extra column to table with edges.

Here is link to [pgrouting workshop](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/) it will guide you through all process from import of data to first generated route. It's using osm2pgroutin to import data, but I suggest you use osm2po instead.

Comment: So I need to delete the tables and data generated by osm2pgsql and use osm2po?

Comment: If only thing you need is routing this is correct, if you need also visualization you'll need it also. Osm2po creates only one table and it's used only for routing

Comment: I added some information about step-by-step instruction

Answer (score 1):

So as Jendrusk mentioned, when you generate a route you will pass the function a SQL query to select the edges for the graph you want to solve, 'select * from edges where the_geom && <bbox>' You can model blockages using point and radius, lines, or polygons that you want the route to avoid by adding to the query above avoidance zones like:

'select * from edges where the_geom && <bbox> and not st_dwithin(the_geom, point, radius) and not stdwithin(the_geom, line_or_polygon, 0.0)'

If you have lots of these avoidances then put them in a table and do a join to eliminate the edges that are used to build the graph. If the edges are not there the route is forces to find a way around the avoidance.